# "Variable not defined" error in total and average computation

Tags: python, variables

I wrote this program to find sum and average, and got "Variable not defined" error. Can anyone solve it?

```
a=int(input("Total Numbers you will input for calculation: "))
Sum = 0 # Running Totalis b
for x in range (a-1):
    c=int(input("Enter your input number {0}.".format(x+1)) # c is for next number
    Sum = Sum + c
Total=b/10 # For Total
print("Total sum of the number you entered is {0} and their average is {1},".format(b,d))
```

Comment: Does below worked for you >

Answer (score 0):

In your code that prints out the sum and average, you refer to the variables `b` and `d`, neither of which actually exist. That is the cause of your immediate problem, the "Variable not defined" issue.

The *sum* of the numbers is stored in the `Sum` variable which you should use rather than `b`. The *average* is not calculated anywhere unless your calculation for `Total` is meant to do this but, if that's the case, you should choose a more appropriate name *and* calculate it correctly (dividing by `a` rather than by ten).

On top of that, your use of range is incorrect. You should be using `a` rather than `a-1`, since `range(n)` *already* gives you the values `0 .. n-1`, a toal of `n` different items.

---

So, with all that in mind, and using some better (self-documenting) variable names (and catching the problem of entering a non-positive count), you could opt for something like:

```
count = int(input("Total Numbers you will input for calculation: "))
if count > 0:
    sumOfNums = 0
    for x in range(count):
        num = int(input("Enter your input number {0}.".format(x+1))
        sumOfNums += num
    avgOfNums = sumOfNums / count

    print("Total sum of the number you entered is {0} and their average is {1},".format(sumOfNums, avgOfNums))
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at below:

```
a=int(input("Total Numbers you will input for calculation: "))
sum = 0 # Running Totalis b
for x in range (a):
    c=int(input("Enter your input number {0}.".format(x+1)))
    sum +=c
avg=sum / a # For Total
print("Total sum of the number you entered is {0} and their average is {1},".format(sum,avg))
```

Comment: This would be a decent answer if you had actually explained what the issue *was* rather than just dumping some code and making readers try to figure out the fix. I'd suggest you just add a little note explaining that.

Comment: Agreed, but I was expecting OP to ask if he really dont know what was wrong. But Sure I will consider explaining in future as well.